# Why consumer stopped if message doesn't contain message selector condition?

Tags: java, jms

I recently work with jms and I have such a question. I have to received message 1)All messages 2)Only where type = 'LIQUID'. I created two consumers

```
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue(QUEUE_FOR_RECEIVED);
        QueueBrowser queueBrowser = session.createBrowser(queue);
        Enumeration enumeration = queueBrowser.getEnumeration();
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        MessageConsumer liquidConsumer = session.createConsumer(queue, "type = 'LIQUID'");
```

First received all messages, second only with `type = 'LIQUID'`. But second consumer just stopped application if message doesn't contain `type='LIQUID'`

```
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            ObjectMessage ss = (ObjectMessage) consumer.receive();
            System.out.println(ss.getObject());
            ObjectMessage msg = (ObjectMessage) liquidConsumer.receive(); // here consumer stopped if message doesn't contain type ='LIQUID'
            System.out.println(msg.getObject());
            enumeration.nextElement();
        }
```

How it can be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the application stopped is because [`javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive--) is a *blocking* call. In other words, it will block further execution until a result is returned. If the queue doesn't contain any messages which match the selector then the call to [`javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive--) will block indefinitely. That's the expected, documented behavior.

If you don't want to block indefinitely here you could:

1. Receive messages asynchronously (e.g. using a `javax.jms.MessageListener` implementation)
2. Use [`javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receive(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receive-long-) and pass a timeout to `receive` so that the call returns if no messages are received after the given timeout.
3. Use [`javax.jms.MessageConsumer.receiveNoWait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html#receiveNoWait--) which will attempt to receive the next matching message and if no matching message is immediately available it will return.